# May I use ROS this way?

Tags: ros, wireless

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am new to ROS.  I have a robot, which collects data through its sensor. And I have a laptop with ROS residing on Ubuntu. I may want to send the sensor data to the laptop through a router. Is there anyway to implement this. The robot does not have ROS on it. It has a tailored Fedora on it.

Many thanks
Yoshi

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/167691/may-i-use-ros-this-way?/) by [Yoshida](https://answers.ros.org/users/18231/yoshida/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2014-05-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

you can use  [QUpsocket](http://www.bogotobogo.com/Qt/Qt5_QUdpSocket.php) to send data from your robot to Ros on your laptop

---

Originally posted by [Hamid Didari](https://answers.ros.org/users/6486/hamid-didari/) with karma: 1769 on 2014-05-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1